# Serialize bulk data by JSON JavaScriptSerializer in C#?

Tags: c#

How can i serialize bulk data by using JSON JavaScriptSerializer in C#?
I tried but got error which mentioned below

**"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property"**

Anyone tell me how can i serialize bulk data plz???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Comment: You might have a look at  [The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108743/the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property-in/35025467#35025467)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jsJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 jsJson.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
```

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't solved my problem. I am facing problem while using DataContractJsonSerializer for bulk data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer don't allow more data like thousand row taken from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been caused by one of your properties being simply too long in length. Can we see some code and background regarding the data involved?