# The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. in MVC3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jsonresult

MVC3 (.cshtml File)

```
$.getJSON(URL, Data, function (data) {

                    document.getElementById('divDisplayMap').innerHTML = data;

                    if (data != null) {
                        $('#myTablesId').show();
                        tdOnclickEvent();

                    }
                    else {
                        $('#myTablesId').hide();
                    }
                }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { debugger; });
```

on Server Side

```
 public JsonResult ZoneType_SelectedState(int x_Id, int y_Id)
    {
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
     result.Data = "LongString";//Longstring with the length mention below
    return Json(result.Data,"application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

from the server side i am passing the string with the length of 1194812 and more than that.
but i am getting the error saying the

```
"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."
```

Please help me out ASP

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom ActionResult which will allow you to specify the maximum length of data that the serializer can handle:

```
public class MyJsonResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly object data;
    public MyJsonResult(object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        // You could set the MaxJsonLength to the desired size - 10MB in this example
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        response.Write(serializer.Serialize(this.data));
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
public ActionResult ZoneType_SelectedState(int x_Id, int y_Id)
{
    string data = "LongString";//Longstring with the length mention below;
    return new MyJsonResult(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `Controller` method as shown below:

```
public JsonResult ZoneType_SelectedState(int x_Id, int y_Id)
{
    var result = Json("LongString", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return result;
}
```