# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds

Tags: c#, java, json, serialization

> """"""""""""""""""Error during serialization or deserialization using
>   the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the
>   value set on the maxJsonLength property.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"""""""""""""""""

I tried all the answers but still now am getting this error anyone please help.

Comment: Have you actually tried increasing the value of the `maxJsonLength` property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109328/ef-to-ajax-string-exceeds-maxjsonlength-with-less-than-250kb/21109329#21109329

Follow this .

It works for me.

Comment: You might have a look at  [The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108743/the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property-in/35025467#35025467)

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) linked by fejescoco, you must specify a maximum length in your configuration.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="9001"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Using an old-style ASP.Net WebMethod, I got this error and this was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It says you can specify a length in your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the value of the MaxJsonLength property applies only when you explicitly create an instance of the JavaScriptSerializer class.

Answer (score 1):

We had a json object returning from the web service. code was as below

```
    JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
.
.
.
    return s.Serialize(bomDataObject);
```

we had about 5000+ rows causing the above error in serialization.

visited the following links to get an idea of the maximum json size limits:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data. We set the code to following to work for our scenario for large data... ofcourse adds load on server and network to load data but it is huge data and we need to displau it !!

```
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
s.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
.
.
.
.
.

return s.Serialize(bomDataObject);.
```

Comment: Seems odd to me that the max wouldn't be set by default.